# Zoom and select in a d3.js ARE NOT WORKING

Tags: angular, d3.js, canvas, scale, brush

Im trying to select data after zooming but d3.event.selection is always getting same values. Any one have an idea please ?

```
  private zoomChart(DataType: any[], color) {
    this.createChart(DataType, this.t, color);
    this.zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0, 1000])
        .on("zoom", () => {
            const transform = d3.event.transform;
            this.t = transform;

          this.draw(this.context, transform, DataType, this.train, 
         this.gxAxis, this.gyAxis,        
         this.xAxis, this.yAxis, this.x, this.y)
        });

    this.canvasChart.call(this.zoom);
    this.canvasChart.style('z-index', 1);
    this.svgChart.style('z-index', 1);
   }
    private selectionChart(DataType: any[], color) {
    this.zoomChart(DataType, color);
    this.brush = d3.brush().extent([
        [0, 0],
        [this.width, this.height]
    ])
        .on("start", () => {
            this.brustStart(DataType);
        })
        .on("end", () => {
            this.brudhtest(DataType, this.train, this.dataSelection, this.t);
        });
    if (!this.svgChart) {
        this.svgChart = this.svgChart
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "brush")
            .style("color", "red");
    }

    this.svgChart.call(this.brush);
    this.svgChart.style('z-index', 1);
    this.canvasChart.style('z-index', 0);
 }


      brudhtest(test, test2, dataSel, transform) {

        let extent = d3.event.selection
        console.log(extent)
       console.log(transform.k)
       if (!extent) return;
        var x0 = (extent[0][0]),
        x1 = (extent[1][0]),
        y0 = (extent[0][1]),
        y1 = (extent[1][1])


        let elementsOfInterest = test.filter(element => {
            if (
                x0 <= this.x(element[a])
                && this.x(element[a]) <= x1 &&
                y0 <= this.y(element[b])
                && this.y(element[b]) <= y1
            ) {
                console.log(x0);
                 }})
```

This is the code. When i dont zoom, the selection is correct, but when i do a zoom and then i select it did not work, the brush waork only when i select the same zone as i did not zoom .
Any idea please ?

Answer (score -1):

I get the answer. 
I have to change this.x(element[a]) to scaleX(element[a])